# VSTO Add-in doesn't compile anymore when a single .xaml file is added to the solution

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, vsto

Let's consider an Excel VSTO Add-in and add in it a class like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public Range GetCell(Worksheet worksheet)
    {
        return worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
    }
}
```

Let's compile it; it works even if it does nothing.
Now, add a UserControl (WPF) to the project, without referencing or using it: just add the item.
If you recomplie you'll receive the error:

```
CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

It refers to the returned type of the member `Cells[1,1]`.

Attention! Sometimes the error doesn't even show up if you don't put "Build Only" in the box shown down here.

It seems like something about dynamic is disabled... but why?

[image: Build Only Box]

#### Possible solution

It's still feasible to typecast when needed, infact this works:

```
return (Range)worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
```

The problem is that office object model is already quite verbose and it is heavily dependent on dynamic. That means that in a real application you would need *a lot* of such typecasts, ending up in having a bunch of typecasts per line.
Not to mention that this problem may indicate something very wrong happening somewehere so I would rather solve this than resorting to typecast as a workaround.

I tested this on VS2017 with VSTO Add-in 2010 and VSTO Add-in 2013-16, same result. .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: have you tried to clean the solution?

Comment: Yes, without success. Actually, the Shweta Solution worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please disable and enable interop types for excel, it will sort it out.

Complete library name, as seen in the project references: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
The option to disable and then enable is Embed Interop Types in the reference properties.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, though in my case I was adding an additional XAML file to a VSTO project that already had other .xaml files. The underlying problem is apparently a latent issue from the VSTO project template:

```xml
    <Reference Include="Office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
      <Private>False</Private>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
      <Private>False</Private>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
```

Changing the value of `EmbedInteropTypes` from `true` to `True` in the .csproj fixes the compile issue. This is what is accomplished by changing the Embed Interop Types to False and back to True again in the reference Properties.

I only had to do this for the Excel reference to get the project to compile again but notice it's wrong on the Office reference too.

In my case, it seems nearly certain that the problem is somehow a conflict related to the fact that my XAML file's root element is `Application` (as in `System.Windows.Application`) when there also exists the interface `Microsoft.Windows.Interop.Excel.Application`.